# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'XXX.ClassName'

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have created a class named Student and I have the following code inside Program.cs:

```
public static IList<Student> Students { get; private set; }

private static void AddStudent()
    {
        /*try
        {
            Console.Write("First name: ");
            //Students.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name was left empty.");
        }*/

        Console.Write("First name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Last name: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();            

        var newStudent = new Student {FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName}; //if I use try-catch block, it says: The name 'firstName' doesn't exist in the current context

        Students.Add(newStudent);

        Console.WriteLine("The new student is added. \nEnter any key to return to main screen.");
        Console.ReadKey();
}


public static void SortStudents(IList<Student> students)
    {
        string temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < students.Count; j++)
            {
                if (string.Compare(students[i].ToString(), students[j].ToString()) < 0)
                {
                    //swap
                    temp = students[i].ToString();
                    students[i] = students[j];
                    students[j] = temp; //error here
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(students);
    }
```

Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string FieldOfStudy { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to implement an algorithm that will sort the entered names alphabetically, but it throws the error there. How can I fix that? I am also trying to use the try-catch block but it throws the error I have commented inside the code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wouild you expect a string (`temp`) to be convertible to `Student` (the contents of your list)?  Also, don't use try/catch for validation, control-flow, etc.

Comment: `temp = students[i].ToString()` - why `.ToString()`? Because `temp` is a string. Why is `temp` a string?

Comment: Can you show your Student class? Do you have implemented an override for ToString in that class? If not then your code doesn't make sense. A student cannot be converted to a string with ToString (and of course the same is true when you want to convert a string to a student)

Comment: @AndrewMorton because otherwise it says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'XXX.ClassName' to 'string'

Comment: @Steve just edited the question code

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'XXX.ClassName'

Comment: Why did you call `.ToString()` on one of the student objects inside your swap code? Why not just `temp = students[i]; students[i] = students[j]; students[j] = temp;`? (and yes, `temp` would have to be of type `Student`, not `string`) If you're using a newer C# compiler, you can even do this one-liner: `(students[i], students[j]) = (students[j], students[i]);`, and remove the `temp` variable.

Comment: Now, compiler errors aside, what exactly do you hope to gain by sorting the student objects by the result of calling their `.ToString()` method? Unless you override this method it will simply return the full type name, which in this case would be simply `"Some.Namespace.Student"`, and all the objects will return that. In other words, you're not going to sort those students at all. In order to sort the students by ... something ... you're going to have to use that something.

Comment: @KirkWoll then what can I use to prevent the user from entering invalid input, like entering numbers or other characters to the name, or a big number as age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the commentators have pointed out you will *likely* need to access the properties of `Student` and compare them, and then swap the Objects.

So something like this:

```
public static void SortStudents(IList<Student> students)
    {
        //We change this to Type Student, not string.
        Student temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < students.Count; j++)
            {
                //We look at the Properties of the object, not the Object.ToString()  
                if (string.Compare(students[i].FirstName, students[j].FirstName) < 0)
                {
                    //Here we are swapping the objects, because we have determined 
                    //Their first names aren't in alphabetical order.  
                    temp = students[i];
                    students[i] = students[j];
                    students[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        //For loop, or Foreach loop here to iterate through your collection (ILIST)
    }
```

Comment: that's ok, but when I run the code I don't get the list of names but this: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DQSSIAssignment.Student]. What can I do?

Comment: So in this case you have a collection of objects `Student`.  You'll want to iterate through all students in your list and print either `student.FirstName` or whatever property you want to display on the `Student` class.  You'll want to use another For loop or a Foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason the `Student` class can not implement this “sorting” logic by implementing the `IComparable` interface? Using a `List<Student>` to hold the `Student` objects will use this `CompareTo` method to “sort” the objects. This will allow the class to be “sorted” anyway you want. In this case it is sorted by last name then first name. Have you tried to do this? It may look something like below…

```
public class Student : IComparable {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
  public string Gender { get; set; }
  public string FieldOfStudy { get; set; }

  public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    Student that = (Student)obj;
    if (this.LastName.Equals(that.LastName))
      return this.FirstName.CompareTo(that.FirstName);
    return this.LastName.CompareTo(that.LastName);
  }
}
```

Then, to “sort” a `List<Student>` would simply be…

```
Students.Sort();
```